# Using Charles Proxy for Android emulator Eclipse with Kindle Fire

Tags: android, android-emulator, proxy, kindle-fire, charles-proxy

How do I set up the proxies on the programs so that I can test a kindle fire app with charles proxy?



**Problem statement:**


I am trying to test an app that we are creating. We are using Eclipse (Android SDK) to open an emulator for the Kindle Fire. The issue we are having is Charles is not receiving information from the Kindle Fire Emulation. I know that I need to set up a proxy on my Mac to have the two programs talk to each other.



**Request**


Detailed instructions on how to properly set up the proxies.



**Programs on the Mac OSX**


Charles

Android SDK, aka Eclipse

Kindle Fire Emulation


Thanks guys.

Comment: Have you tried asking this question to Charles directly?  Can you provide details of what you've tried to do so far?  There are a number of resources out there (including on the Charles Proxy site) that describe how to set it up, and it's not clear if you've tried using those already.

Comment: I am guessing that you will need to set the proxy for the network connection on the Fire emulation to go via the port that Charles is listening to

Answer (score 3):

In the Android emulator run configuration add an Additional Emulator Command Line Option:

```
-http-proxy http://LOCAL_IP:8888
```

Where LOCAL_IP is the IP address of your computer, not 127.0.0.1 as that is the IP address of the emulated phone.